# Bug when indexing date column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, parsing, indexing

I'm trying to make pandas recognise the first column as a date.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
cl = open('cl.csv')
cl = pd.read_csv('CL.csv', parse_dates=['Date'], index_col=['Date'])
cl.info()
```

Then to visualise the price:

```
fig = px.line(cl, y="Adj Close", title='Crude Oil Price', labels = {'Adj Close':'Crude Oil Price(in USD)'})
```

But it gives back a ruined chart:

[Date indexed chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLBXk.png)

If I comment out 'parse_dates=['Date'], index_col=['Date'])' and just leave 'cl = pd.read_csv('CL.csv')' the chart will look just fine.

[Chart without date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fc9TM.png)

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

If you print `c1` out and the dates look fine, then the reason behind the graph could likely be that your `c1` wasn't sorted by `Date`, do the following before visualizing it:

```
c1 = c1.sort_values('Date')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem can be caused by the type of date format that column contains (`'Date'`), so researching the documentation, I quote the following: *For non-standard datetime parsing, use `pd.to_datetime` after `pd.read_csv`. To parse an **index** or **column** with a mixture of timezones, specify date_parser to be a partially-applied `pandas.to_datetime()` with `utc=True`*. See Parsing a [CSV with mixed timezones](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#io-csv-mixed-timezones) for more, then you could replace `cl = pd.read_csv('CL.csv', parse_dates=['Date'], index_col=['Date'])` with `cl = pd.read_csv('CL.csv', parse_dates=['Date'], date_parser=lambda col: pd.to_datetime(col, utc=True))`